# Mystery in Pennsylvania garden

Tags: identification, shrubs

This one has proven to be a real mystery, even when we asked a Master Gardener.
Serrated edges, each cup 2-3 inches in width, about a foot in height.

[image: serrated edge]

Answer (score 4):

Looks to me like a Sedum.  The closest of the many varieties might be Sedum ellacombianum
(also called Sedum kamtschaticum ssp ellacombianum)

Fresh green leaves and star-shaped yellow flowers in summer. 6” X 18”.   Full sun, well drained soil.   Very vigorous, almost weedy, drought and cold tolerant. A native of Asia and hardy to –30 degrees F or about (-30 deg C)

It is described in more detail [here](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/gardens-gardening/your-garden/plant-finder/plant-details/kc/f550/sedum-kamtschaticum-var.-ellacombeanum.aspx).

If I'm right it will have little yellow flowers.

Comment: Excellent identification, my appreciation for this accurate and rapid reply! Den